# NOT EXISTS / NOT IN clause in hive

Tags: hive, hql, hiveql

I have tried to find how could I use NOT EXISTS / NOT IN clause in HIVE and have not found a solution that HIVE has to offer.

I basically need to find id's that exist in one table and not exist in the second table and I can't find a way to jump over it. Please advise

Comment: Hive supports NOT EXISTS and NOT IN. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+subqueries#LanguageManualSubQueries-SubqueriesintheWHEREClause. You can add NOT, everything else is the same. In the plan it will be the same join operator as if you are using LEFT JOIN+filter.

Answer (score 0):

In hive you can use `left join` to detech not exist type clause. If you share your sql, i can be more precise. But here is some hint.

```
select 
a.id
from
a
left outer join b on a.id = b.id
left outer join c on a.id = c.id
where
b.id is null  -- make sure data doesn't exist in b
and c.id is not null  -- make sure data exists in c
```

left join and where clause make sure data exist in table c but doesn't exist in b.